# How to insert text from inside a vimscript loop?

Tags: loops, vim, while-loop, insertion

It appears from the `:help while` documentation that :

```
NOTE: The ":append" and ":insert" commands don't work
properly inside a ":while" and ":for" loop.
```

And I can confirm they don't. But what should I use then to insert text from inside a loop?

Comment: What are you trying to do? But it soundalike you could just build the whole string up in a variable and then insert the contents of that variable.

Comment: Have you tried setline() function? This should be working if you just want to insert text into a buffer even in while loop I think. Otherwise, you may buffer text in while loop, then insert them after the loop.

Comment: @FDinoff I've just wrote a function that can help me navigate from one argument to another inside a headed expression, and I would like to reuse it in reorganizing arguments of a long expression on several lines. I think that working on the whole string in a variable is the right solution indeed. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Tacahiroy Yeah, I think you're both right, don't hesitate to post an answer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `:insert` and `:append` commands are mostly meant for interactive use. In a Vimscript, you can instead use the lower-level `setline()` and `append()` functions, which do work well in a loop. (They are also easier to use, because you can directly pass a List of lines to them.)

Comment: This did the trick, and also changed my vimscripting philosophy: thank you! ^ ^