# Write lines in Vim using a for loop

Tags: vim, text

How to make Vim write lines into a file according to a very simple arithmetic pattern?

Example:

```
foo1
foo2
foo3
...
foo99
foo100
```

I came up with the following solution using Ex commands

```
:for i in range(1,100)
:  execute "normal ofoo" . i
:endfor
```

but I am convinced there must be something more straightforward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert text from inside a vimscript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511027/how-to-insert-text-from-inside-a-vimscript-loop)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do it with macro.

First type one line:

```
foo1
```

then

```
qqYp<c-a>q
```

finally replay the macro:

```
98@q
```

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten about CTRL-a. Although it is not a problem here, the macro is much slower than the loop.

Comment: @Siméon from scratch, I would say macro is faster. because you have to write the function/statements first, then call it.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
:let l = map(range(1,100), '"foo".v:val')
:put=l

" Unfortunately put won't accept the expression, append() would though
call append(line('.'), map(range(1,100), '"foo".v:val'))
```

Comment: This is an interesting method, a bit more natural and concise than mine.