# How to insert text in vimscript

Tags: vim

I have the simplest requirement in a vimscript. I've been searching on Google for quite some time e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511027/how-to-insert-text-from-inside-a-vimscript-loop) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690386/writing-a-vim-function-to-insert-a-block-of-static-text) [3](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/). I just want to insert a line of text!

Suppose I have a file with lines:

```
aaa
bbb
ddd
eee
```

And I just want to add the missing line `ccc` after the line `bbb`.

I have the beginnings of a vimscript function:

```
function! addLine()
  normal /bbb
  " MISSING LINE
  wq!
endfunction
```

What should the missing line be?

Note that I want to then call this script on a bunch of files using using `vim -c 'call addLine()' FILE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Vimscript, I'd avoid `:normal`-mode operations in favour of [builtin functions](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#function-list) that do the same things:

```
function! AddLine()
    let l:foundline = search("bbb") " Can return 0 on no match
    call append(l:foundline, "ccc")
    wq!
endfunction
```

[`search()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#search%28%29) and [`append()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#append%28%29) should be more convenient to work with in a function than `norm /` and `norm o`.

Comment: While it's hard to explain, that's not going to work in my actual use-case. Are you saying it's simply not possible to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Oh it's possible alright, you would need a combination of `exec` and  `norm` to get keypresses like `Enter`, and generally messier quoting as a result. Try explaining anyway.

Comment: Generally, the advice is that you shouldn't edit a question if it invalidates existing answers, but I don't mind. Go ahead and edit as you see fit. I'll try to fix accordingly, or delete if I can't.

Comment: It's actually impossible without asking a completely new question. Give me a bit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447788/how-to-insert-text-in-a-vimscript-without-using-the-builtin-functions

Answer (score 2):

While it isn't vimscript, your search and replace task across a bunch of files sounds like a job for `argdo`:

```
:argdo %s/bbb/&\rccc/ge | update
```

Comment: I mean technically that is vimscript... just not wrapped in a a function.