# How to insert text in a vimscript without using the builtin functions

Tags: vim

Suppose I have a file with the following text:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
bbb
ccc
eee
```

I need to add a missing line `ddd` after the *second* occurrence of `ccc`.

For that reason, use of the built-in `search()` function, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447394/how-to-insert-text-in-vimscript), won't work, because that will find the first occurrence.

I have the beginnings of a vimscript function:

```
function! addLine()
  normal /bbb
  normal /bbb
  " MISSING LINE
  wq!
endfunction
```

Is it possible to do this just using normal mode etc? If so, how?

Comment: Successive calls to `search()` should find the next occurrences. `call search("bbb") | call search("bbb")` or `for i in range(10) | call search("bbb") | endfor`, etc.

Comment: If I do `search("ccc") | search("bbb")` I seem to end up at the first `bbb` not the second?

Comment: Which line did you start from? Starting from the first line, `:call search("ccc") | call search("bbb")` gets me to line 4 (the second `bbb`).

Comment: Hmmm yes seems to behave differently if called from command mode inside the file as opposed to inside a function.

Comment: Ah, I see. Try `search("ccc", "e")` instead - it should move the cursor to the end of the match, but it seems that behaviour varies depending on it was called, so specifying that behaviour explicitly using the `e` flag should fix that.

Comment: Actually [this](https://gist.github.com/alexharv074/c56e8ff4b190d27da3b9c81a95a02d10) works. If you want to convert that to an answer? That said I would still welcome a solution based on normal mode. I'm sure it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `:normal`, any presses of <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Carriage Return, `<CR>`) or <kbd>Escape</kbd> needed by the normal mode command need to passed to it. So `/...` command would look like:

```
exec "normal /bbb\<cr>"
```

You need the <kbd>Enter</kbd>, without it the `/` command gets cancelled.

So your function would look like:

```
exec "normal /ccc\<cr>noddd\<esc>"
```

(Pressing `n` to repeat the search, then `o` to start input in the next line, then <kbd>Escape</kbd> to exit insert mode.)

Or split into multiple `:normal`s:

```
exec "normal /ccc\<cr>"
exec "normal /ccc\<cr>"
exec "normal oddd\<esc>"
```

You have to be careful that the text being inserted here doesn't have [strings that might be special](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-string).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Muru's excellent and helpful answer, I wanted to provide the actual code:

```vim
function! AddLine()
  normal /bbb\<cr>n/ccc\<cr>oddd\<esc>
  wq!
endfunction
```

Note that:

- `\<cr>` appears as `^M` in the file and is entered as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>.
- `\<esc>` appears as `^[` in the file and is entered as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

To understand the script `normal /bbb\<cr>n/ccc\<cr>oddd\<esc>`:

- `/bbb\<cr>` - find the first line `bbb`
- `n` - find the next match
- `/ccc\<cr>` - find the next line `ccc`
- `o` - enter insert mode and enter the text:
- `ddd`
- `\<esc\>` - exit insert mode.

This can be rewritten using the Vim functions as:

```vim
function! AddLine()
  call search("bbb")
  call search("bbb")
  let l:foundline = search("ccc")
  call append(l:foundline, "ddd")
  wq!
endfunction
```

Both of those functions correctly edit the file as required, although of course I do agree that the use of Vim functions is cleaner. If you can remember all the functions!

See also:

- `:help` in Vim
- My [tests](https://gist.github.com/alexharv074/9838a85485790a0b049ff20057707f76).

Comment: Remembering is what :help is for

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing.
And didn't find the answers.
But when iwas trying a few things i found a solution.

I know and hope that you have already find the answer but the others here is the thing to do :

When you are in the vimscript menu, just press ***esc***, then ***+***

At this point you can add new content. To be sure that it's working, you can see an "insert mode" at the bottom of the screen from the vimscript menu.
Hope that it helps.